# Combine Multiple src in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a HTML raw template that have to be converted using `React` way. I already followed the tutorial how to add external `JS file` in React component. But I have multiple JS files. In tutorial, it explains just 1 src.

I want to be more efficient to write the code with combine it. I implemented it in `React Hooks`:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "assets/js/jquery-min.js";
    // script.src = "assets/js/popper.min.js";
    // script.src = "assets/js/bootstrap.min.js";
    // script.src = "assets/js/dashboard.js";
    // script.src = "assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js";
    // script.src = "assets/js/wow.js";
    // script.src = "assets/js/jquery.nav.js";
    // script.src = "assets/js/scrolling-nav.js";
    // script.src = "assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js";
    // script.src = "assets/js/main.js";
    // script.src = "assets/js/form-validator.min.js";
    // script.src = "assets/js/contact-form-script.min.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: I'd include those scripts in the HTML, not in React, if at all possible

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have custom JS file. So I'm not want to conflict with another components

Comment: If other components also might try to add script tags due to their dependencies, you'll have problems